# Duplicate classes found in Gradle when trying to use Paging Library 3

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-paging

I am trying to implement paging using Paging Library 3. However, I cannot run my project after doing all the necessary steps (paging source, flow, and etc). This is the list of my dependencies:

```
Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine found in modules jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.4.1) and jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1)
Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.Active found in modules jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.4.1) and jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1)
Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.AwaitAll found in modules jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.4.1) and jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1)
Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.AwaitAll$AwaitAllNode found in modules jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.4.1) and jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1)
Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.AwaitAll$DisposeHandlersOnCancel found in modules jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.4.1) and jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1)
```

It's not the full stack trace. Some of my dependencies:

```
// Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1'
// Paging
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-alpha12'
 // Image Compressor
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:3.0.0' // this lib also uses coroutines
```

Also, I've tried excluding some dependencies this way:

```
implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-alpha12' {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', module: 'kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm'
```

But it produces the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-alpha12() for arguments [build_cmaofa0fil3wjmmcunq4oc9m5$_run_closure2$_closure8@2e68c056] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I tried running an example project downloaded from a raywenderlich tutorial and it runs fine with the same dependencies. Migrating to Paging v2 resolves the issue but I would like to use the new functionality in the updated version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write the dependency like this to avoid using from the below-stated module and group. You can also check for the module and/or package with the duplicate classes by checking the error message and pasting it here.

```
implementation ('androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.0.0-alpha12') {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', module: 'kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm'
}
```

Comment: I've already said in the question that I had tried doing that and it didn't help :(

Comment: For me, it didn't work at first until I added the brackets. Add the brackets and sync gradle again.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Your answer is correct. Brackets help somehow. Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using wrong dependency. change to below line :

```
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.0.0-alpha12"
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I had to use a stable version of paging.
For me, the below solution worked. I hope this solution also might be helpful in some cases.

```
implementation ('androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx'
 }
```